# How to display var_dump() results in a pretty format?

Tags: php, var-dump

Sometimes I'm using the `var_dump()` for debugging which outputs unformatted results.

Is there a way which can display structured information with colors, etc...

Comment: If you want to debug better - use a real debugger (Zend debugger, Xdebug are 2 examples) and not `var_dump`, `print_r` etc...

Comment: A **second** link in the suggested answers column at the right

Comment: `Zend_Debug` springs to mind, along with the old-fashioned `print_r` along with `<pre>` tags

Comment: This is what XDebug will make your dump look like: http://blog.pascal-martin.fr/public/xdebug/xdebug-var_dump-1.png

Answer (score 13):

```
echo "<pre>";
var_dump($var);
echo "</pre>";
```

Answer (score 4):

My favorite way of viewing `var_dump` is to install [Xdebug](http://xdebug.org/). You should then be able to get formatted and colored output as [shown on their website](http://xdebug.org/docs/display).